# Junit throws NullPointerException on EntityManager

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit4

I am running `Junit Test` cases which is throwning `NullPointerException` Here is my Junit Test Class Structure

```
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   public class EmployeeTest {

      @InjectMocks
      EmployeeRepository empRepo;        

      @InjectMocks
      EmployeeService empService;

      @Mock
      EntityManager entityManager;

       List<Employee> empList=new ArrayList<Employee>();
      @Before
       public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
      }


     @Test
     public void getEmployyeList(){
       Employee e = new Employee(111,'Raunak','kumar','Hero Inc');
       List<Employee> empList=empService.getAllEmployee();
       Employee e1 = empList.stream().filter(emp->emp.getEmpId()==111).findAny().get();
       assertEquals(e,e1);
     }

   }
```

And On the `EmployeeService` i am using `EntityManager` looks like

```
    public class EmployeeService{

     @Autowired
     EntityManager em;

     public List<Employee> getAllEmployee(){
           return  em.createNativeQuery("select e.* from employee e").getResultList();
     }
   }
```

When i am `debugging` the code found that `em.createNativeQuery("select e.* from employee e")` returns null. From the `Rest API` its working fine.

tried with

```
 when(empRepo.findAll()).thenReturn(empList);
     assertThat(users, containsInAnyOrder(
                hasProperty("lastName", is("Kumar"))
        ));
```

But `empRepo.findAll()` also return `[]`

Answer (score -1):

you have to stub mock entity manager using mockito's when and thenReturn  in your test case (getEmployyeList) like below , this should resolve NPE

```
@Test
public void getEmployyeList(){
    Employee e = new Employee(111,'Raunak','kumar','Hero Inc');
    Query query = mock(Query.class);
    when(entityManager.createNativeQuery(anyString())).thenReturn(query);
    doReturn(Arrays.asList(e)).when(query).getResultList();
    List<Employee> empList=empService.getAllEmployee();
    Employee e1 = empList.stream().filter(emp->emp.getEmpId()==111).findAny().get();
    assertEquals(e,e1);
}
```

Comment: in that case i have to re write complete service logic in the test case again ?

Comment: No you are not re writing that's called Mocking is the act of removing external dependencies from a unit test in order to create a controlled environment around it. Typically, we mock all other classes that interact with the class that we want to test. 
so in this case, We are stubbing the database connection instead, and “fool” our class to think that it is talking to a real EntityManager, while in reality, the EntityManager is a Mockito stub. This way, we have complete control over what is returned by the database connection without having to deal with an actual database. hope this helps

Comment: `entityManager.createNativeQuery(anyString())` i m using in services only.in junit i am only expecting results in `empService.getAllEmployee()`.

Comment: @manikantgautam I have edit the answer , Please try now

Comment: @Abhisekkumar edited again can you please check now

Comment: just wondering where are we using `getAllEmployee` service method in your answer ?

Comment: @Abhisekkumar in the test case , Let me again right the whole code for you:) in the answere

Comment: this is not working i am getting cast Exception at `query`and NPE still do exist `The method thenReturn(javax.persistence.Query) in the type OngoingStubbing<Query> is not applicable for the arguments (org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query)`

Comment: @Abhisekkumar asp per your error it seems using wrong import for Query class .you should use correct Query class import ie. javax.persistence.Query in you Test Case class.

Comment: still getting `NPE`

Comment: It seems you have missing something if possible can you please share the complete code (post to GitHub) i will fix that